# Write/Debug Azure Automation Runbook in PowerShell ISE

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to write a Runbook (PowerShell Workflow) for Microsoft Azure Automation using the PowerShell ISE. There are certain commands that are not available in the PowerShell ISE, that are exclusively available inside of the Azure Automation environment.

- Get-AutomationVariable
- Get-AutomationConnection
- Get-AutomationPSCredential
- Get-AutomationCertificate
- Set-AutomationVariable

There is a [blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/orchestrator/archive/2014/03/27/authoring-sma-runbooks-in-the-powershell-ise.aspx) (I still can't find any *reference documentation*) on how to fake (emulate) the exclusive Azure Automation commands using the *Emulated Automation Activities* PowerShell module, available for download from the [TechNet Gallery](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Service-Management-d4edfbf4). However, this article requires that you install the Service Management Automation (SMA) component that is included with Microsoft System Center 2012 R2 Orchestrator.

Since I am trying to develop a Runbook for Azure Automation, I do not have any need to install SMA. How do I write/debug an Azure Automation Runbook from PowerShell ISE without having to install SMA locally?

Answer (score 1):

That blog post is for SMA only. In the future we will be publishing a similar guide for Azure Automation. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/8de3c565-7fa0-49b6-b5e6-1b0a586883da/any-tips-on-how-to-develop-for-azure-automation-without-actually-relying-on-the-service?forum=azureautomation for more details.

Comment: Have you published the guide?

Comment: Still working on it. If you send me your email somehow I can give you a draft version to start with / provide feedback on.

Comment: I sent you an email to your alumni account. Thank you.